# Restore SQL Server DB from backup but to a different name (same server)

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

Using SQL Server 2019, I need to use T-SQL for this, not SSMS. All of this is on the same server.

I have the backup file at `C:\SQL_MASTER_DB\MASTER_DB_BACKUP.BAK`. I want to restore this backup to the same server but to an entirely new database name. This is part of an automated process where databases are created. The structure of these databases are the same hence the single point backup location.

Here is a screenshot from the `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` process:

[image: Backup file screenshot]

Searching this site I came up with this...

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyNewDBName
FROM DISK = 'C:\SQL_MASTER_DB\MASTER_DB_BACKUP.BAK'
WITH MOVE 'MyNewDBName_Data' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MyNewDBName.mdf',
     MOVE 'MyNewDBName_Log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MyNewDBName_log.mdf',  
     NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
```

I get this error:

> Msg 3234, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
> Logical file 'MyNewDBName_Data' is not part of database 'MyNewDBName'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Bottom line is I'm expecting a new database to be created and two new files created for that database. I know I'm not seeing something here but need assistance where I am going wrong.

-Mike

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm an idiot ... no sooner did I post this that I found the answer and my error.

This worked as it should...

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyNewDBName
FROM DISK = 'C:\SQL_MASTER_DB\MASTER_DB_BACKUP.BAK'
WITH MOVE 'MASTER_DB' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MyNewDBName.mdf',
MOVE 'MASTER_DB_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MyNewDBName_log.mdf' ,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
```

The problem was the move names. They need to match what is in the back file.